# ability to pick file in iphone and upload it to server

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, dialog, nsfilemanager

I know that there is NSFileManager class to manipulate with files in local application folder using:

```
NSTemporaryDirectory()
```

But what if I want to pick a file from iPhone storage, I didn't even find a default iOS application like 'fileManager' or 'fileExplorer' in Android to browse my files. Can someone explain me how it works in iOS. Or there is only an ability to manipulate files in my application temporary folder?

Comment: There is no "iPhone storage" in the sense you are thinking. Apps are restricted to accessing files within their own sandbox. Apps can access specific pieces of data, such as photos and videos from the photo library with user permission but they use specific APIs for this, not generic file access

Comment: Thank you, @Paulw11. That is what I want to hear).

Comment: Checkout this process which might be helpful in some ways: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2774343/1463604